# How to translate this oracle spatial mask into st_relate postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to translate oracle spatial queries into postgis queries for my job, and I don't understand how to convert this sdo_relate clause into a st_relate close :

OracleSpatial code :

```
WHERE sdo_relate (a.geometry, 
                  b.GEOMETRY,
                 'mask=contains+inside+covers+coveredby+overlapbdyintersect+equal+overlapbdydisjoint'
                 ) = 'TRUE'
```

Can I put more than 3 arguments in the st_relate function ?

I've tried this :

```
WHERE 
    st_contains(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) AND 
    st_contains(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) AND 
    st_covers(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) AND 
    st_coveredby(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) AND 
    st_contains(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) AND 
    st_intersects(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) 
    AND st_disjoint(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) 
    AND st_equals(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) 
    AND a.GID = '142284 '
GROUP BY b.SOUS_TYPE, b.TYPE_PRESCRIPTION, a.geometrie, b.geometrie, b.TRIG_COMM
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: what do you get from `st_relate(a.geometrie,b.geometrie)`?

Comment: It creates an error, I think st_relate needs 3 arguments :'(

Comment: which error message you get?

Comment: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 1: ...CAD_PARCELLE a, ELYPU.PLU_PRESCRIPTION_S b  WHERE st_relate(...
                                                             ^
État SQL : 42804
Caractère : 392

Comment: WHERE st_relate(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) AND a.GID = '142284 '  GROUP BY b.SOUS_TYPE, b.TYPE_PRESCRIPTION, a.geometrie, b.geometrie, b.TRIG_COMM

Comment: it's because you're using it in the `where` clause. Put it in the select :)

Comment: btw: the first two and the fith conditions in your where clause are identical `st_contains(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) AND  st_contains(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) `

Comment: Thank's for the tips :) but now I have an other error :'( ERROR:  Error performing intersection: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 2048245.0692044531 7270045.3678812813 at 2048245.0692044531 7270045.3678812813

Comment: I see. To make our lives easier, could you please add two sample geometries (preferably with create table statements in a fiddle) and the exact expected result?

Comment: It would be difficult datas come from my work and it's not authorized to put it in public :'( thank's a lot for your help btw

Comment: can you try this? `WHERE 
    st_contains(ST_MakeValid(a.geometrie), ST_MakeValid(b.geometrie)) AND 
    st_covers(ST_MakeValid(a.geometrie), ST_MakeValid(b.geometrie)) AND 
    st_coveredby(ST_MakeValid(a.geometrie), ST_MakeValid(b.geometrie)) AND 
    st_intersects(ST_MakeValid(a.geometrie), ST_MakeValid(b.geometrie)) AND
    st_disjoint(ST_MakeValid(a.geometrie), ST_MakeValid(b.geometrie)) AND
    st_equals(ST_MakeValid(a.geometrie), ST_MakeValid(b.geometrie)) AND
    a.GID = '142284 '
GROUP BY b.SOUS_TYPE, b.TYPE_PRESCRIPTION, a.geometrie, b.geometrie, b.TRIG_COMM`

Comment: OK that's better now I do not have errors but there is no result I think this the good way

Comment: nice, the error was related to one of your geometries that has a self-intersection. What we need to do now is to convert all operations you used in the string to functions. What I don' get it how can b.geom be inside b.geom `AND` be equal at the same time (last condition)

Comment: Should I remove the st_equals ?

Comment: the question is rather if you need `AND` or `OR` in your conditions ..

Comment: ok i try with OR the request is processing :)

Comment: depending on your table size, it might take a while ;) It is just a guess..  I honestly know almost nothing about OracleSpatial :-\

Comment: I think with oracle spatial if you write mask = covers+contains it is equal to cover or contains https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_relate.htm#SPATL1039

Comment: my 1st suggestion was rather to get the matrix from two geometries that you know that work and let postgis calculate the matrix for you, e.g.`SELECT ST_Relate(a.geom.b.feom) FROM a,b WHERE a.GID = '142284'`, than I would use this matrix as a 3 parameter in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: OK that's weird It works with only st_intersects :O

Comment: if your use case only requires that, this might me the easiest solution ;)

Comment: THANK'S A LOT :) !!

Comment: I just added an answer. If it helped you, consider accepting and upvoting it, so that other users can also profit from it.

Comment: The combination of masks connected with '+' means an inclusive OR, so, as already suggested use OR, not AND. Also that long accumulation of masks means all possible topological relationships are valid - except TOUCH (adjacency). I am curious as to what sort of application would require this ...

Answer (score 0):

- In your query you're checking `st_contains(a.geometrie, b.geometrie)` three times, which obviously isn't necessary.
- Some combinations in your `WHERE` clause will never work. For instance, `st_disjoint(a.geometrie, b.geometrie) AND st_equals(a.geometrie, b.geometrie)` will never bring any result, as two geometries cannot be equal `AND` disjoint at the same time - a *schrödinger geometry* perhaps? ;-).
- To avoid the self-intersection error you might wanna use `ST_MakeValid` to wrap your geometries (see comments).
- Instead of simply translating the Oracle Spatial mask into PostGIS functions, I suggest you to reevaluate your use case and just use the functions you actually need. As you mentioned in the commentds, a simple `ST_Intersects` might suffice.
- If you want to stick to ST_Relate, check [these examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM#Coverage_on_possible_matrix_results) of string codes and build your own.

You can let `ST_Relate` compute the matrix for you, so that you can use it in the `WHERE` clause. Use it with geometries that you know should work, e.g.

Data Sample

```
CREATE TABLE a (geom geometry(polygon,4326));
CREATE TABLE b (geom geometry(polygon,4326));

INSERT INTO a VALUES ('SRID=4326;POLYGON((-4.5412382957234065 54.216850443917195,-4.506219374824969 54.216850443917195,-4.506219374824969 54.19677082652654,-4.5412382957234065 54.19677082652654,-4.5412382957234065 54.216850443917195))');
INSERT INTO b VALUES ('SRID=4326;POLYGON((-4.5233855125202815 54.20681185515958,-4.484246718574969 54.20681185515958,-4.484246718574969 54.185923774806604,-4.5233855125202815 54.185923774806604,-4.5233855125202815 54.20681185515958))');
```

[image]

```
SELECT ST_Relate(a.geom,b.geom) FROM a,b;

 st_relate 
-----------
 212101212
```

Than use it in the where clause:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM a 
JOIN b ON ST_Relate(a.geom,b.geom,'212101212');

 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b94a691324209d5374af9080fa4afb3c)

Comment: Maybe `SELECT count(*) FROM a JOIN b
ON ST_Relate(a.geom,b.geom,'212101212');` is preferable ?

Comment: @wildplasser in the given example it wouldn't really matter.. but you're totally right, a spatial join is the best choice. Just edited with your suggestion. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. It annoys me that many GIS people/software still use the old style syntax. (maybe it is in the code generators?)

Comment: @wildplasser most likely because we're old :D my theory is that many many gis use cases rely on cross joins, and the old syntax is the shortest way to do it.

Comment: I prefer to write cross joins as `FROM a JOIN b ON 1=1` , which stands out more than a missing WHERE clause term... ( `1=1` comes in handy for code generators, too) See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049346/905902

Comment: @wildplasser I also prefer explicit cross joins :) specially when dealing with large tables, an incomplete `where` clause with the old syntax can give you a huge headache :D